# What is the distance between point [4, 7] and the nearest point on the circle centered at [2, 9] with radius 2? Provide at least 4 digits of accuracy

Tags: python, math

PYTHON:

What is the distance between point [4, 7] and the nearest point on the circle centered at [2, 9] with radius 2? Provide at least 4 digits of accuracy.

Hint: The distance between a point and a circle is the distance between the point and the center of the circle minus the radius of the circle. You can use the point-to-point distance code described in this week's videos.

I believed the answer was in this function:

```
def dist(p, q):
       return math.sqrt((p[0] - q[0]) ** 2 + (p[1] - q[1]) ** 2)
```

I have tried a number of different combinations but can't seem to find the answer. Help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This might be a right candidate for http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. Questions on mathematics can be asked at http://math.stackexchange.com for example.

Comment: This question is also a homework problem for the Coursera course Integrated Programming in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have this function and considering the hint, the solution is really simple:

```
dist([4.0, 7.0], [2.0, 9.0]) - 2.0
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should take abs() of that number to allow points inside the circle.

    

@user2941633: The function you provide correctly gives the distance between two points, but [4,7] and [2,9] are not the points for whom you want the separation. The hint tells you how to correct for that, as this answer does.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize I had to add - 2.0 on the end. That makes sense now!